# How to Create a Database for Multiple User Access on a Central Drive

Tags: database, sql-server-express

For my sins I have become the Excel Whiz for my department (believe me, in my department, just being able to open Excel puts you ahead of the pack!).

I created them a spread sheet for developing their annual budget.  This worked well but now they want more!  Essentially what they want is a single point for all cost information such as budgets, spend tracking, forecasting, reporting, analysis etc that can be accessed by any member of the department, i.e. multi user, at any time to read/write data.

My plan was to develop my VBA programming skills by downloading Visual Studio Express and learning C# (seems to me that more people are talking about C# these days than VB?) so that I can build a GUI front end that is compiled into a .exe file that sits on each persons PC for them to use as and when required.  This seems to be going ok.

The bit I am stuck on is the database behind the GUI.  I had intended to 'simply' create a database on our departments central 'O:\' drive and get the .exe programme to read/write data from/to it. My company has not installed Microsoft Access on our PC's, therefore, I had intended to use SQL Server Express.  However, having done some reading and looked at SQL Server Express I think I am misguided/out of my depth?

My understanding is that you cannot simply read/write from a database with a C# front end.  You need a management tool inbetween?  I have tried to get my head round what I can and cannot do but now I have brain overload.

Please can someone provide direction on how to create a simple database for multiple user access via a C# front end and where things need to sit, i.e. local individual PC versus shared central drive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said in my post, my company will not install access on our PC's so I was looking for a non access solution.

Comment: Sorry, haven't noticed that. They won't let you install Access, but they let you put your own .exe file? If it's for security reasons - it does not make sense. If financial - OK, try OpenOffice Base ( https://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html ) - it's free.